# How to pass in an array of integer pointers

Tags: c

my function:

```
int f1(int* r1, int* r2, int* r3, int* r4) {

    *r1 = 1;
    *r2 = 343;
    *r3 = 34;
    *r4 = 3;

    return c; // c = 1 if success
}

caller:
f1 (&r1, &r2, &r3, &r4);
```

if I want to simplify my function, should I pass in an array of four `int` pointers?  or should i do it with an array of four `int` ?

```
int f1(int* r1[4])?
```

or

```
int f1(int r1[4])?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since arrays decay into pointers when passed to a function, an array would do:

```
void f(int *p)
{
     p[0] = 1;
     p[1] = 2;
     p[2] = 3;
     p[3] = 4;
}

int arr[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
f(arr);
```

Comment: `p[4] = 5` -- this little addition to your code will cause buffer overflow. There is no hint to recognize it. Quite the contrary, in the case of `void f(int p[4]) good compiler or code analyzer or just careful programmer will catch buffer overflow

Comment: @kotlomoy Honestly, this is not a real-world example. If there's an array, there's an explicit size too. Always. No need to split hair.

Comment: I'm not sure that hardcoding an array size into an argument list is a shining beacon of programming best practice, either. What if he wants it to handle three one day, or five? Just pass the size as a separate argument.

Answer (score 0):

When array is used for function's parameter,it's a pointer.
So

```
int f(int *p) == int f(int r1[])
```

You don't need to write `int f(int r1[4])` .Because the compiler don't care the size of the 1D array when passed to a function.

```
int f1(int* r1[4]) == int f1( int **p )  // That's not what you want.
```

Comment: "the compiler don't care the size of the array " - half true, try passing a 2D array to a function ;)

Comment: yeah,my bad.I should have say more

Answer (score 0):

The true C99 way to do this is to have:

```
int f(int p[static 4])
{
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 2;
    p[2] = 3;
    p[3] = 4;
    return c;
}
```

The `static 4` inside the square brackets indicates to the compiler that the function expects an array of *at least* 4 elements. clang will issue a warning if it knows at compile-time that the value you are passing to `f` doesn't contain at least 4 elements. GCC may warn too but I don't use this compiler often.

Answer (score 0):

- if I want to simplify my function, should I pass in an array of four
  int pointers? or should i do it with an array of four int ?

Array of four int

```
int f1(int r1[4])
{
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 2;
    p[2] = 3;
    p[3] = 4;
}
```

Since array decay into pointer you can omit the size of array

```
int f1(int r1[])
```

or

```
int f1(int * r1)
```

But it is a bad way. For example, `p[4] = 5` will cause buffer overflow, which compiler can not catch without knowing size of buffer.